# Authentication on flutterflow is not working at the google play store. Although is working on the webapp

Tags: authentication, web-applications, firebase-authentication, flutterflow

I'm developing our app with flutterflow.

Google login is working at the webapp (app.cityflow.app) but does not work at the google play application. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.cityflow.first)

Anyone knows something about that?

Thanks so much in advance for your time!

Try to see problems with Firebase but everything looks great